# Bxslider Unwanted Top & Bottom White Space

Tags: whitespace, margin, padding, bxslider

I'm not sure where the extra white space on the top and bottom of my slider is coming from. Is it padding or margins? If anyone can assist me, it would be greatly appreciated.

jsfiddle.net/fH3EL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of the bx-slider CSS file. The Bx-slider adds a margin of 5px to your bxslider

You will have to edit [this CSS file](http://www.coppermstudio.com/CSS/jquery.bxslider.css)  and make this change

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    border: 0px;
    left: -5px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/fH3EL/2/)

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the quick response. I figured it was something in MY CSS that I was missing.

Comment: I have the same issue... Now there is a gap between the image and the viewport. I'll try and sort it out and edit my comment when I get a solution.

Cannot find the issue but .bx-wrapper img { margin-top: -16px } will sort it out for now.